# Have I misunderstood gc() in R

Tags: r, memory-management, garbage-collection

After running a long script, I looked at Windows Task Manager (Windows 7 64bit) and saw that over 3 gig of memory was used.  I removed all variables from memory.  The memory was still used.  So I searched SO and found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169373/memory-usage-in-r).  I tried running gc().  I get the following:

```
> gc()
          used (Mb) gc trigger  (Mb)  max used   (Mb)
Ncells  893182 47.8    1835812  98.1   1835812   98.1
Vcells 2061325 15.8   19962389 152.4 407302954 3107.5
```

This is after a few minutes of waiting.  I was expecting much of the memory to be freed. Am I missing something? Thanks.

Comment: it is usally a good habit to follow rm(list=ls()) by a gc() call - to prompt R to free the memory.

Comment: No, @wd11, it's not. Most of these gains are mythical.

Comment: who am I to argue with you - Dirk; 
but I have experienced that 'long' code streaks gained a bit on the stability side if I threw in an occassional gc() every now and then ... especially when running code in the RStudio IDE on Windows it semmed to help;  
nevertheless could be that wishfull thinking obscured my perception ...

Answer (score 3):

One possible explanation, from [Hadley Wickham's Advanced R book](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html#gc):

> This number [i.e. the amount reported "used" by `pryr::mc()`, which should agree with the values given by `gc()`] won’t agree with the amount of memory reported by your operating system for a number of reasons:
>   ...
>   ...
>
> 2. Both R and the operating system are lazy: they won’t reclaim memory until it’s actually needed. R might be holding on to memory because the OS hasn’t yet asked for it back.